# Convert hexadecimal notation literally to string or vice versa

Tags: python, hex, implicit-conversion

The function I'm writing gets a checksum (format: '*76') as a string (isolated from an NMEA string). This checksum in string format is called 'Obs' (Observed from string). It then computes the checksum from the rest of the string and gets that answer as hex (Terminal: 0x76), this will be called 'Com' (Computed from string). Now I need to convert one to the other to compare them agains each other.

I've tried stuff like:

```
HexObs = hex(Obs) #with Obs as '0x76' and '0*76'
```

Which gives me an error.

and

```
StrCom = str(Com)
```

Which gives: '118'

There were no previous questions in which I recognised my question.
Does anyone know how to convert one to the other? Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from a string hex representation, use:

```
>>> int('0x76', 16)
118
```

The second argument is the base.

To go from an integer to a string hex representation, use:

```
>>> hex(118)
'0x76'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're problem is getting the original into an actual hex form

```
tobs = '76'
obs = hex(int('0x' + tobs, 16))
```

that will give you an actual hex value to compare

alternately you could use:

```
tobs = '76'
com = '0x76'
tcom = com[2:]
```

then compare tobs & tcom